# Class 'Srmklive\PayPal\Services\ExpressCheckout' not found

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I am using a Laravel paypal plugin called `srmklive/paypal`.

php version : 7.3.12 Laravel version : 6.2

Please help on this.

The logs show me this error :

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'Srmklive\PayPal\Services\ExpressCheckout' not found in file C:\wamp64\www\chefruntown\app\Http\Controllers\User\Web\CartController.php on line 214
```

This is my controller view

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\User\Web;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Srmklive\PayPal\Services\ExpressCheckout;

class CartController extends Controller
{
    public function handlePayment(Request $request)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $cart = getUserCart();
        $items = getUserCart()->cartItems;

        $product = [];
        $product['items'] = [
            [
                'name' => $items,
                'price' => $items,
                'qty' => $items
            ]
        ];

        $product['invoice_id'] = 1;
        $product['invoice_description'] = "Order #{$product['invoice_id']} Bill";
        $product['return_url'] = route('success.payment');
        $product['cancel_url'] = route('cancel.payment');
        $product['total'] = $cart->total;

        $paypalModule = new ExpressCheckout;

        $res = $paypalModule->setExpressCheckout($product);
        $res = $paypalModule->setExpressCheckout($product, true);

        return redirect($res['paypal_link']);
    }
}
```

Comment: which version of the package you are using??

Comment: Version 3 package

Comment: if you want to use express check out, you have to use v 1..

Comment: Is there any solution to use express check out in version 3 package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to Version 1 of the srmklive/paypal Package worked